# SLT Replicate View - Error: SQL0601N The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name

Tags: slt

Situation: We wan to to real-time ETL using SLT (SAP Landscape Transformation) Replication Server.

I learned that I have to define views in transaction LTRS.

So I try to add a view to an existing Table like in the Screenshot. Unfortunately I get the Error: SQL0601N The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name ...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that you use transaction LTRS before adding the table to the configuration in transaction LTRC.**

Another cause could be that the table exists in the target database. **So make sure that the target table does not exist yet.**

On tests about the issue I realized that transaction LTRS where the error occurs does not create a table - even though the error message indicates otherwise.